# Structure and Format for Skype history databases

Tags: database, skype

Skype seems to use .db, .db-journal, and .lock files, as well as subdirectories full of .dat files for storing conversation histories.ces

Are the formats of these files available anywhere, or is there an open source library for accessing them that I can examine and possibly modify?  I think several libraries allow the retrieval of conversation history, but I would like to also achieve insertion of conversation history records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are SQLite databases.

You can use SQLite or a [tool](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools) to see its contents.

Also, most of this content is available through Skype API (I am aware of [COM](http://developer.skype.com/resources/Skype4COM-1.0.33.zip) and Java bindings)

Best

Adriano

Comment: Thanks, I'll give some of those tools a try later tonight.